# Append a chart in the middle of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dashboard that looks like this:[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz70X.png), the gauges are going to display information dynamically.What I want to achieve is that when pressing the "+ INFO" button of a gauge, a graph is displayed. the chart code:

HTML: 
`<div id="TemPlot" style="width: 80vw; max-height:60vh;"></div>`

JavaScript: `Plotly.newPlot(myPlotDiv, data, layout, { responsive: true });`

My first problem is how to place the chart on the html page, since I don't want it to appear at the end of all gauges. My second problem is how to know from the script which graphic should I show to update the information.

I attach the code of the dashboard in case it is useful to understand:

```
<main>
  <section class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge1"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge2"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge3"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
          <canvas id="gauge4"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge5"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge6"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge7"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge8"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image-container">
        <canvas id="gauge9"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <p class="card__title text--medium">
          Sensor Information
        </p>
        <div class="card__info">
          <p class="text--medium">30 Min</p>
          <p class="card__price text--medium">+INFO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be à bit complicated with only classes but you could use :

```
let myelement = document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[indexoftheelement];
```

which is deprecated. But you can get your element by knowing and typing manually the index of it.
once you got the element you want you can add the content you want by using appendChild :

```js
//getting your element
let element=document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0];
//creating p html tag
let mycontent = document.createElement("p");
//putting text into it
mycontent.textContent = "hello";
//adding it to the element you want :
element.appendChild(mycontent);
```

```html
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

as for the second question, you might want to add an id on your "+ INFO"button or dinamically create the buttons in javascript in order to fetch it later with for instance :

```js
let myText = document.createElement("p");
myText.textContent = "hello";
mybutton1.onclick = ()=>{document.body.appendChild(myText)};
```

```html
<button id="mybutton1">click</button>
```